# Is "scuff" an adjective in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I have found this sentence as an "example" for the "scuff" as a verb in the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scuff).

> Do you have anything for getting ​rid of **scuff** ​marks on ​shoes?

Comment: Looks and reads like one to me.  I'll defer to others for a sure answer.

Comment: As @tchrist says, it's a noun, employed as an attributive; it's carelessness on the dictionary's part to post that sentence under the *verb* rubric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *scuff* is a noun, which per the OED means:

> A mark made by scraping or rubbing.

A *scuff mark* is a mark made with a scuff, and therefore it is a noun used attributively to modify another noun. That does not make it an adjective. The adjective would be something like *scuffed*.

Comment: So "a scuff mark is a mark made with a mark made by scraping or rubbing."  Doesn't the redundancy of 'mark' in 'scuff mark' bug you?